# Gt bike without serial number

Tags: identify-this-bike, serial-number

I'm having trouble finding if this frame is a legit GT or not.
It has stamped GT at front and back of the frame and in the dropouts. But don't have serial number. I'm guessing it's a 90's Gt aggressor frame but don't know.

Comment: Can you add some photos, please?   Use [edit]